# css: how to make the third div line up with the first div

Tags: html, css

css codes:

```
<style>
.wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 950px;
}
#box2 a{
    color: blue;
}
</style>
```

html codes:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="box1">
        <p>Using XCLASSes is fragile: Neither the core, nor extensions authors can guarantee that XCLASSes do not break if the underlying code changes (for example during upgrades). Be aware that your XCLASS can easily break and has to be maintained and fixed if the underlying code changes. If possible, you should use a hook instead of an XCLASS. If the given code does not provide a hook for your specific problem, you could ask the extension author or the core to implement a hook.
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="box2">
        <p><a href="#">school</a></p>
        <p><a href="#">Job Club</a></p>
        <p><a href="#">member</a></p>
    </div>
    <div id="box3">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td class="item-header">Career Resources</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="item">Workbook+ 200 online resources</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="item">Personal Career Management Dashboard</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="item">Job Searching and Resume Posting</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Question:

Now it displays like this:

```
box1
box2
box3
```

If do not change html codes, only change css codes, is that possible to make it display like this?

```
box1  box3
box2
```

I mean make `box3` line up with `box1`, is this possible?

Comment: You can use css columns with fixed height.

Comment: The only ways you can do this without changing the HTML is with absolute positioning, like @Vikas suggested and if the height of div is constant you can set a negative margin-top like this http://jsfiddle.net/YP7xk/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [This Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YP7xk/). You need to `position` the box 3 `absolute` with wrapper

**CSS**

```css
.wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 950px;
    position: relative;
}
#box2 a{
    color: blue;
}
#box1, #box2, #box3 {
    width: 450px;

}
#box1, #box2 {
    margin-right: 50px;
    float: left;
}
#box3 {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: This is correct (as in answers the question) but will fail horribly on mobile.  Here's a [quick demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YP7xk/1/) of what it would look like on iPhone.

Comment: Then you need to use media queries to solve this issue on iPhone, decrease the width of boxes in small devices.

Answer (score 0):

An albeit crude solution:

With div #box2 and #box3 in reverse order.

See [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HR3nv/)

```css
.wrapper{
    border: 1px solid #888;height:600px;width:300px;
}

#box3 {
    border: 1px solid #888;background-color:#CCC;width:300px;float:left;
}

#box2 {
    border: 1px solid #888;background-color:#CCC;width:800px;height:130px;float:left;
}

#box1 {
    background-color:#CCC;width:300px;min-height:100px;float:left;border: 1px solid #888;
}
```